# Formal Proof - Multiple Premises

Tags: formal-proofs

I am trying to learn proof for my degree and in one of the exercises, it gives a proof of what seems to have multiple premises at the start. I can't seem to even figure out to start on the proof.

Premise: $A, B\to C$

Conclusion: $(A\to B)\to C$

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have adopted the proof calculus from the book *Logic in Computer Science: Modelling and Reasoning about Systems by Michael Huth and Mark Ryan*.
$$
\begin{align}
&1\quad A&&\text{premise}\\
&2\quad B\to C&&\text{premise}\\
\hline
&3\quad A\to B&&\text{assumption}\\
&4\quad B&&\text{$\to$e 3,1}\\
&5\quad C&&\text{$\to$e 2,4}\\
\hline
&6\quad(A\to B)\to C&&\text{$\to$i 3-5}
\end{align}
$$